# File.Move fails when preceded by a File.Delete

Tags: c#, io

We have a MoveFile method which usually work, but keep failing at a customer site.

```
if (File.Exists(target))
{
    File.Delete(target);
}

File.Move(source, target);
```

The call to `File.Move` fails repeatedly with

> ```
> System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
>
>    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
>    at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
> ```

We have error handling surrounding call to that method, but we can't figure out why `File.Delete` is not working and is not throwing anything.

We though about file permission, but then the `File.Delete` would have throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Are there any other reason that would make `File.Move` fail with a "file already exist" when it is preceded by the deletion of that specific file?

Comment: Curious: what happens if you wrap your File.Move in a similar if(File.Exists(..))?

Comment: One possible reason for Move to fail after Delete is that the File handle may be still opened in some process in the system for instance Anti Virus scanner or Search Indexers. Since File.Delete remark section clearly states that  "Windows NT 4.0 Platform Note: Delete does not delete a file that is open for normal I/O or a file that is memory mapped. " , instead it just mark as Delete and further calls give access denied exception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you reverse the logic?

```
File.Copy (source, target, true)
```

to overwrite the target then

```
File.Delete(source)
```

Comment: All right, this was tested and work. Thank you, sorry for the delay in accepting the answer, its not easy to test thing like this when you are dependent on a TeamViewer access to deploy an application at the customer site.

Comment: I know the feeling! I should probably point out (if it's not blindingly obvious) that there is a disadvantage to this if the file is large: a file move will be pretty quick if the source and destination are on the same disk, whereas copying the data will potentially take some time. But on smaller files the speed difference will be insignificant.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I've found that the system tends to delete the file "slower" than your program is running.

Ideally you need to check whether the file has been deleted, before trying to then move a file into its place. Usually you can get round this with a simple Thread.Sleep(200) or similar, but it's probably not the most reliable way!

Comment: A slightly more reliable way based on this would be to poll the existence of the file in a loop with a `Thread.Sleep` and wait for it to be deleted, up to a certain maximum timeout.

Comment: It's an unavoidable race condition. Retrying repeatedly is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this can happen if someone else has the file open with the FileShare.Delete option (i.e. allow deletion).  In such a case, the file will be marked for deletion, but won't actually be deleted until the other handle is closed.

I'm not sure what processes could have a file open in such a way - antivirus software would be one possibility.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might get better results out of:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, overwrite);
```

so that `overwrite = true`

this will overwrite the old file if it exists rather than worrying with deleting it separately.

You may then delete the original as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even better way that avoids copying or polling the delete ---
Let's assume we have File_A and File_B. We want to move File_B over File_A. 
Steps:
1) Rename (move) File_A to a third name, File_C.
2) Delete File_C.
3) Rename (move) File_B to File_A.

```
File.Move("File_A", "File_C");
File.Delete("File_C");
File.Move("File_B", "File_A");
```

This eliminates the race condition where the original file being deleted hangs around while the new file is being moved to the original file.