# How do I release a file held by BitMap class

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(filePath);
...
image.Save(someOtherPath);
image.Dispose();
File.Delete(filePath);
File.Move(someOtherPath, filePath);
```

The File.Delete line raises the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.
```

How do I get the C# to release the lock it has on the file?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704982/file-move-fails-when-preceded-by-a-file-delete

Comment: Could be silly question but...have you closed some kind of picture viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
using(var image = new Bitmap(filepath))
{
    image.Save(someOtherPath);
}


File.Delete(filePath);
File.Move(someOtherPath, filePath);
```

Comment: will the dispose complete fully before the File.Delete line is called though

Comment: Right - that works.  Why does it work as opposed to my original code?

Comment: Me too. I wonder why `using`'s way of disposing objects works while `.Dispose` method does not?

Comment: I think it is not different from the original code. The problem is with the copy after delete as I wrote in the comment to the question, but maybe sometimes the delete is happening fast enough to allow copy right afterwards

Comment: I'm taking a guess that calling dispose directly doesnt cause it to be garbarge collected immediately

Comment: Garbage Collector is not relevant here

Comment: The above code works on its own, but not when I also include the image manipulation inside the using as well.  I have put a pause before the file.delete which will wait for user input before continuing and no matter how long I wait the file is still locked.  I have also tried using GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers before the delete and it still has no affect.

Answer (score 0):

```
the mistake came from the file open by your Image class
Image image;

using(FileStream myStream = new FileStream(path))
  {    
     image = Image.FromStream(myStream);
  }
```

Comment: Tried this too with and without the using, but get a problem when I try to save the image